# iOS maximum video size can be uploaded to server

Tags: ios, iphone

I am loading a video file to server through `ASIHTTPREQUEST`.
What is the maximum video size that can be uploaded to server?

Comment: There is no maximum size, you can upload any size video. Obviously it will, however, take a very long time depending how fast the phone's connection is. (I didn't downvote, but perhaps that's why someone did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit forced by using `ASIHTTPREQUEST` itself. It is just a wrapper around the `CFNetwork` API. But there are other factors that may affect, like your connection speed, amount of space in server itself etc.